# PostgreSQL::OID::Array does not support `serialize` feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've tried to deploy to Heroku with `array` column. But this error occurs. And what can I use method instead of `serialize` is better?

```
ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::ColumnNotSerializableError (Column `days` of type ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Array does not support `serialize` feature.
Usually it means that you are trying to use `serialize`
on a column that already implements serialization natively.
```

// migration file

```
class AddDaysToSchedule < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :event_types, :days, :text, array: true
  end
end
```

// schedule model

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :days, Array
```

Please let me know you knoe how to stack overflow.

Comment: you don't need `serialize` declaration, when using postgresql native array type.. just remove it

Comment: Presumably you're developing on something other than PostgreSQL (SQLite perhaps?) but deploying on PostgreSQL. Don't do that to yourself; always develop, test, and deploy on the same stack. ActiveRecord doesn't really offer much in the way of database portability.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 :=>

```
class AddDaysToSchedule < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :event_types, :days, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

No need to serialize

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  #serialize :days, Array
```

Solution 2:=>

I would suggest you to go like this: -

```
class AddDaysToSchedule < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :event_types, :days, :string
  end
end
```

And serialize column in model as array

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :days, Array
end
```

To store values:-

```
sh = Schedule.new()
sh.days.push(day_value)
sh.save
```

To get array value

```
 sh = Schedule.find(x)
 sh.days => will return array of days
```

Comment: What do you mean by "However postgresql doesn't support array data type"? PostgreSQL *does* support native array columns without the `serialize` kludge.

Comment: Thanks but I can't display `array` as `string`. like this error NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "\"---\\n- 0\\n- 1\\n- 2\\n- 3\\n- 4\\n- 5\\n- 6\\n\"":String):

Comment: @ShunYamada How did you store value in column? and it should return array not string.

Comment: @ShunYamada Check the updated answer , as i have mentioned to get and insert array value, hopefully this will help you.

Comment: @Gabbar Thanks so much for your help. However I don't know why but I couldn't store my array to db and PG don't recognize this as an array.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to use, say Sqlite in development environment, but Postgres in production, you can serialize conditionally based on the database type. Example:

```
serialize :days, Array if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'SQLite'
```